# How to set selected area in Listbox

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate

I need to do something like that:

[image]

It's Listbox with custom DataTemplate for elements. (I drew green a whole one element of list.)

Now I have this:

[image]

If it's real - how to change my DataTemplate(or Listbox styles) to get first resul? (Somehow to set selected area)

DataTemplate

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TrackDataTemplate">
    <Grid Margin="0,-5,0,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstPlatformName}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <Path x:Name="Node"
            Margin="10,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
            Data="M3.1999443,36.501999 L47.300057,36.501999 47.292366,36.517475 C43.192585,44.521747 34.86105,50 25.25,50 15.638952,50 7.3074172,44.521747 3.2076359,36.517475 z M25.25,0.5 C38.919049,0.49999976 50,11.580952 50,25.25 50,27.599367 49.672657,29.87228 49.061096,32.025615 L48.919384,32.501999 1.5806161,32.501999 1.438906,32.025615 C0.82734287,29.87228 0.5000003,27.599367 0.5,25.25 0.5000003,11.580952 11.580953,0.49999976 25.25,0.5 z"
            Fill="{DynamicResource white75}" Stretch="Fill"
            Width="17"  Height="17"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="Connection" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Fill="{DynamicResource white75}"  Height="17" Width="4" Margin="10,2,10,0"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" TextWrapping="Wrap"
            Text="{Binding TsAndChannelNumber}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Listbox

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="1"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTrackSegment}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedTrack.Segments}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TrackDataTemplate}"
    Margin="30,20,30,0"/>
```

Comment: mind adding the datatemplate?

Comment: added DataTemplate code

Comment: datatemplate seems to be correct, its just that the items gets selected completely that's why you are not getting it in the way you want. Just try adding a transparent rectangle on grid row 0 and column 2

Comment: Thanks for Idea!
But if you talk about something like that

    <Rectangle Fill="Transparent" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1"/>

It's not work, but if to use not tranparent color everything works good

A little later I will write working version in answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For complete control over the ListBoxItem you probably need to change the Template in ItemContainerStyle.
Heres a little test project to show what I mean.
NB Ive added 2 grids around your textblocks so that the Background Property can be changed using the Triggers.

Xaml

```
 <ListBox x:Name="MyList">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                            <Grid Margin="0,-5,0,0">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Grid x:Name="PlatformGrid">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstPlatformName}" />
                                </Grid>
                                <Path x:Name="Node"
                                                Margin="10,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                                                Data="M3.1999443,36.501999 L47.300057,36.501999 47.292366,36.517475 C43.192585,44.521747 34.86105,50 25.25,50 15.638952,50 7.3074172,44.521747 3.2076359,36.517475 z M25.25,0.5 C38.919049,0.49999976 50,11.580952 50,25.25 50,27.599367 49.672657,29.87228 49.061096,32.025615 L48.919384,32.501999 1.5806161,32.501999 1.438906,32.025615 C0.82734287,29.87228 0.5000003,27.599367 0.5,25.25 0.5000003,11.580952 11.580953,0.49999976 25.25,0.5 z"
                                                Fill="Blue" Stretch="Fill" 
                                                Width="17"  Height="17"/>

                                <Rectangle x:Name="Connection" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
                                                HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                                Fill="Blue"  Height="17" Width="4" Margin="10,2,10,0"/>
                                <Grid x:Name="TSGrid" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2">
                                    <TextBlock  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding TsAndChannelNumber}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <MultiTrigger>
                                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="True"/>
                                        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="PlatformGrid" Value="Red"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="TSGrid" Value="Red"/>
                                </MultiTrigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
```

MainWindows.cs

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += (s, args) =>
            {
                this.DataContext = this;
                MyList.ItemsSource = LoadSegments();
            };
    }

    private static List<Segment> LoadSegments()
    {
        var segments = new List<Segment>
        {
            new Segment { FirstPlatformName = "FPName01", TsAndChannelNumber = "TSNumber0(ChannelNumber0" },
            new Segment { FirstPlatformName = "FPName01", TsAndChannelNumber = "TSNumber0(ChannelNumber1" },
            new Segment { FirstPlatformName = "FPName01", TsAndChannelNumber = "TSNumber0(ChannelNumber2" },
            new Segment { FirstPlatformName = "FPName01", TsAndChannelNumber = "TSNumber0(ChannelNumber3" },
            new Segment { FirstPlatformName = "FPName01", TsAndChannelNumber = "TSNumber0(ChannelNumber4" }
        };
        return segments;
    }
```

Segment.cs

```
public class Segment
{
    public string FirstPlatformName { get; set; }
    public string TsAndChannelNumber { get; set; }
}
```

You will ideally need to 'Edit a copy' of the ItemContainerStyle template in Blend so you get access to all the standard behaviours and then edit the Trigger IsSelected as above
Hope that helps

Comment: Great Thanks!

                                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="True"/>
                                        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>

this code really helped me

Answer (score 0):

But I suggest to use two ListBox and use `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem`  property to true. So when you make selection on one, it will select the same item on other automatically. And you can define your own data template for each listbox.